# MM_swapImage OnMouseOver not working in IE

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onmouseover

I have an image that the client wants an image swap on mouse over using an area map.

Upon mouse over of each square an image would replace that appears to be a pop up explaining more about that section.

Their old (current) site is written in .ASP and I'm moving this over to .PHP via WordPress. I am using the MM_swapImage and even went as far as to reuse the code they used, which works in IE.

Currently the coding is working in FF, Chrome, Safari, and Opera... everything BUT IE.

Can anyone help?

Here is the coding:

HTML:

```
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/img_ac_clinical1.jpeg" alt="" width="487" height="365" usemap="#img_ac_clinical1Map" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-796" id="img_ac_clinical1" title="img_ac_clinical1" border="0" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/mmover.js"> </script>
<map name="img_ac_clinical1Map" id="img_ac_clinical1" >
<area shape="rect" coords="28,204,169,349" href="#" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('img_ac_clinical1','','http://www.ntst.com.php53-12.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/img_ac_clinical2.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
  <area shape="rect" coords="179,174,317,312" href="#" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('img_ac_clinical1','','http://www.ntst.com.php53-12.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/img_ac_clinical3.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
  <area shape="rect" coords="327,152,456,287" href="#" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('img_ac_clinical1','','http://www.ntst.com.php53-12.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/img_ac_clinical4.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
</map>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}

function MM_reloadPage(init) {  //reloads the window if Nav4 resized
  if (init==true) with (navigator) {if ((appName=="Netscape")&&(parseInt(appVersion)==4)) {
    document.MM_pgW=innerWidth; document.MM_pgH=innerHeight; onresize=MM_reloadPage; }}
  else if (innerWidth!=document.MM_pgW || innerHeight!=document.MM_pgH) location.reload();
}
MM_reloadPage(true);

function P7_Snap() { //v2.65 by PVII
 var x,y,ox,bx,oy,p,tx,a,b,k,d,da,e,el,tw,q0,xx,yy,w1,pa='px',args=P7_Snap.arguments;a=parseInt(a);
 if(document.layers||window.opera){pa='';}for(k=0;k<(args.length);k+=4){
 if((g=MM_findObj(args[k]))!=null){if((el=MM_findObj(args[k+1]))!=null){
 a=parseInt(args[k+2]);b=parseInt(args[k+3]);x=0;y=0;ox=0;oy=0;p="";tx=1;
 da="document.all['"+args[k]+"']";if(document.getElementById){
 d="document.getElementsByName('"+args[k]+"')[0]";if(!eval(d)){
 d="document.getElementById('"+args[k]+"')";if(!eval(d)){d=da;}}
 }else if(document.all){d=da;}if(document.all||document.getElementById){while(tx==1){
 p+=".offsetParent";if(eval(d+p)){x+=parseInt(eval(d+p+".offsetLeft"));y+=parseInt(eval(d+p+".offsetTop"));
 }else{tx=0;}}ox=parseInt(g.offsetLeft);oy=parseInt(g.offsetTop);tw=x+ox+y+oy;
 if(tw==0||(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 4")>-1&&navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")>-1)){
  ox=0;oy=0;if(g.style.left){x=parseInt(g.style.left);y=parseInt(g.style.top);}else{
  w1=parseInt(el.style.width);bx=(a<0)?-5-w1:-10;a=(Math.abs(a)<1000)?0:a;b=(Math.abs(b)<1000)?0:b;
  x=document.body.scrollLeft+event.clientX+bx;y=document.body.scrollTop+event.clientY;}}
 }else if(document.layers){x=g.x;y=g.y;q0=document.layers,dd="";for(var s=0;s<q0.length;s++){
  dd='document.'+q0[s].name;if(eval(dd+'.document.'+args[k])){x+=eval(dd+'.left');y+=eval(dd+'.top');
  break;}}}e=(document.layers)?el:el.style;xx=parseInt(x+ox+a),yy=parseInt(y+oy+b);
 if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 5")>-1 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")>-1){
  xx+=parseInt(document.body.leftMargin);yy+=parseInt(document.body.topMargin);}
 e.left=xx+pa;e.top=yy+pa;}}}
}

function P7_hideDiv(evt) { //v1.3 by PVII
 var b,relT,mT=false; 
 if(document.layers){b=evt.target;if(b.p7aHide){
  b.visibility="hidden";}else{routeEvent(evt);}
 }else if(document.all&&!window.opera){b=event.srcElement;
  while(b!=null){if(b.tagName=="DIV" && b.p7ahD){mT=true;break;}b=b.parentElement;}
  if(!b.contains(event.toElement)){b.style.visibility="hidden";}
 }else if(document.getElementById){b=evt.currentTarget;relT=evt.relatedTarget;
  while(relT!=null){if(b==relT){mT=true;break;}
  relT=relT.parentNode;}if(!mT){b.style.visibility="hidden";}}
}

function P7_autoHide() { //v1.3 by PVII
 var i,g,args=P7_autoHide.arguments;
 for(i=0;i<args.length;i++){if((g=MM_findObj(args[i]))!=null){
  g.p7aHide=true;if(document.layers){
  g.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEOUT);}g.onmouseout=P7_hideDiv;g.p7ahD=true;}}
}

function MM_reloadPage(init) {  //reloads the window if Nav4 resized
  if (init==true) with (navigator) {if ((appName=="Netscape")&&(parseInt(appVersion)==4)) {
    document.MM_pgW=innerWidth; document.MM_pgH=innerHeight; onresize=MM_reloadPage; }}
  else if (innerWidth!=document.MM_pgW || innerHeight!=document.MM_pgH) location.reload();
}
MM_reloadPage(true);
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying for days to figure this out through trial and error as well as research.

Thank you.

Comment: IMHO it would be infinitely easier to just replace *ALL* of the trash macromedia code that dreamweaver spits out with a simple implementation using a standard javascript library (ala jQuery etc) or even a custom method.

Comment: something like this? http://grasmash.com/article/simple-jquery-script-swapping-images-hoverrollover

Comment: Sure that would work, if it isn't an area of interest or expertise I would recommend looking at some ready implementations like the one you posted. The only reason I suggested that route is because I doubt you are going to find any luck with anyone willing to mull over the trash macromedia spits out and try to fix it.

Comment: what verions(s) of IE???

Comment: oh, and by the way, I fully agree with @QuintinRobinson's comment -- throw away all that dreamweaver junk. More than half of the code there is trying to support Netscape Navigator. You really don't need that clogging up your site.

Comment: All versions of IE but works great in everything else. It works currently in IE on their ASP site, which is strange. Maybe it's WordPress. But I also do not know enough to know what of that JS code is Macromedia stuff either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It seems to me like all functions with "P7" are not used. Try deleting them.
- IE is extra picky about semicolons at the end of the line. This would be me first try.
- as other users have suggested, use jquery ... check out the demo further down there: [jQuery .hover() function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)